# WebView Upload Photo doesn't work - AndroidX

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I create webview for uploading photos, when I try it in chrome it working properly, when I use webview it doesn't work any solution?

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is pretty vague. Can you share more details?

Comment: I use javascript to create button for uploading a photo and create a URL from it, when I try to use webview using that URL and press the button, it doesn't work, but in chrome it's work normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java) webview and simply add below line to to your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

Comment: You give me an idea to use Activity Result, it's working now thankyou!